# Symfony2 Warning: file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream

Tags: symfony

My symfony2 application works fine on my laptop which is my development machine. But when I uploded it to hosting provider I get the error stating

```
Warning: file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream in /somepath/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php line 155
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you check permissions and set them to 777 **temporarily** to make sure that this is not an issue? Also, what hosting are we talking about? Own server, virtual machine or hosted?

Comment: It is hosted site and giving 777 did not make any difference. I have now deleted the Ex lock parameter from file put contents since some blog says that it is not supported on NFS so removing it everything works fine now.

Comment: Could really do with finding an answer to this problem as well. Currently suffering from the same issue using Doctrine with CodeIgniter and changing the file permissions did not work.

Answer (score 12):

Try this in your vagrant:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "v-root", mount_options: ["rw", "tcp", "nolock", "noacl", "async"], type: "nfs", nfs_udp: false
```

Comment: my fstab: `10.217.252.83:/home/projects /home/projects nfs rw,tcp,nolock,noacl,async,user,exec 0 0`

Comment: The only thing that was required for me was `nolock`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in NFS options. By default NFS is using NLM locking. In order to disable it you need to edit your `/etc/fstab` file and add `nolock` option to your NFS settings

Example:

```
server:/path           /mountpath    nfs     nolock,nfsvers=2   0 0
```