# laravel file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream

Tags: laravel

I tried to upload my site to laravel to host and be configured but I couldn't load the project. The error is as follows:

> file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the host is not supporting "exlusive locks". I had this problem with Vagrant on a Ubuntu host.
Then you can fix it like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35743592/2707570 
If you have the problem on a remote server you need to contact the provider and ask why exclusive locks are not supported.

Answer (score 9):

Try to remove the following line of code in your path:

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    }
```

and replace it with this one below:-

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
{
    return file_put_contents($path, $contents, 0);
}
```

Comment: worked for  me, this could be a workaround at least or marked as the answer.

Comment: @ClaudiuHaidu your changes will be overwritten as soon as you update Laravel. See my answer below for a more sustainable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently. Running the artisan command: **php artisan config:cache** fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, while using NFS to share my code from my developer machine to my Centos server. The problem seems to be that the server tried to access my NFS-shared files using NLM locking by default, so I had to disable locking in my settings. This is done by adding `nolock` in the NFS options in `/etc/fstab`

This fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps which solved the same issue when I tried to run laravel9 on my Android tablet with termux.**

- Go to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/filesystem.php`
- Then replace the code inside `put` method like shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luog0.png).

Simply change `LOCK_EX` to `LOCK_SH`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when running on a system that doesn't support exclusive [file locks](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Locks.html).

> An exclusive or write lock gives a process exclusive access for writing to the specified part of the file. While a write lock is in place, no other process can lock that part of the file.

There are currently 2 places in Laravel where such locks are enforced for data security reasons: when writing [cache entries](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L76) and [sessions](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Session/FileSessionHandler.php#L95). Note the third argument to [`Filesystem::put()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L185) is `true` in both these calls, which causes it to try and gain an exclusive lock before writing.

The way to resolve this issue is to get the filesystem adapter to not attempt that lock. The approach suggested in one answer is to edit Laravel's library files. This is, as the kids say, the smooth-brain approach. Your changes will be lost on upgrade so must be continually managed.

Instead, write your own custom class, override that method, and configure your application to use it.

Step 1: create `app/Filesystem/Filesystem.php` with these contents:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filesystem;

use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as FilesystemBase;

class Filesystem extends FilesystemBase
{
    public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        // don't pass the value of $lock to the parent method
        return parent::put($path, $contents);
    }
}
```

Step 2: edit `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to register the new class. Don't remove existing registrations, if any, just add this one:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('files', fn () => new Filesystem);
    }
}
```

And that's all. Confirm your provider is working by firing up `php artisan tinker` and entering `app('files')`. You should get an instance of your new class.

Answer (score 0):

Go to filesystem.php inside laravel vendor

Change the put method with these lines:

`public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false) { return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0); }`

In short term LOCK_EX to LOCK_SH

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a local filesystem (ie not NFS) and you are using Apparmor, you will need to add a "k" permission to your storage directory and below.

In my case I have created a file called `/etc/apparmor.d/local/php-fpm` and I put all my overrides there.

`/path/to/laravel/storage/** rwk,`

In Ubuntu, you will find Apparmor logs in `/var/logs/audit/audit.log`. I always forget to look there, when some unexpected issue arises that involves permissions...

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to close the server by closing your batch window you used in starting the server initially.
2. Refresh your browser and make sure the the server has been closed.
3. Start a new development server by typing `$ php artisan serve`
4. Go to your browser and enter the server address generated by the artisan. It's usually http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score -2):

Best Solution for Laravel
Go to /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
delete content function " public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)" line 120.
Finish

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28227945)

Comment: Manually modifying files within your dependencies is not a sustainable solution. Those changes won't persist in version control (or shouldn't) and other users of the project will have to complete this step during setup.