# laravel Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required ../root/htdocs/myapp/server.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have just had a fresh installation of laravel 7 on my xampp set up. when i go to my application i get:

```
laravel Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Users/puseletsokgole/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/all41web/server.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

What might be happening here?

Comment: this seems to have worked : ```php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public -f serve.php```. except now i have a different  problem: ```file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream```

Comment: Does server have access/permissions  to folders /bootstrap/cache and /storage?

Comment: run the project with `php artisan serve` and check if it works or not ?

Comment: And for this error you might need to include path in environment variable of your system. Google it and you will find, i just gave you idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well i ended up doing this:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public -f serve.php
```

and the subsequent error:

```
file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream
```

i followed this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921408/laravel-file-put-contents-exclusive-locks-are-not-supported-for-this-stream
```