# ErrorException file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream IN MAC

Tags: php, laravel

[image: laravel 8 new project error image!]

ErrorException file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream!!

new Laravel 8 project show this error when I open it in chrome http://127.0.0.1:8000
it tried a lot of solutions but there doesn't work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel file\_put\_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921408/laravel-file-put-contents-exclusive-locks-are-not-supported-for-this-stream)

Comment: check my answer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921408/laravel-file-put-contents-exclusive-locks-are-not-supported-for-this-stream

Answer (score -1):

Replace in FileSystem.php (displayed in the error)

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
{
    return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
}
```

With

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false) {
   return file_put_contents($path, $contents, 0);
}
```

[laravel file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921408/laravel-file-put-contents-exclusive-locks-are-not-supported-for-this-stream)

And

https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/969

OR

https://github.com/hasangilak/NoLock